# If I have a list of objects that I want to access from multiple classes where should I store the objects?

Tags: java

I have several classes to store data (DataClassA, DataClassB, etc) and many objects in each class (objectA1, objectA2, objectB1, objectB2, objectB3, etc). Now each of the objects will have an ID number and will be stored in an appropriate hashtable (hashtableA, hashtableB, etc).

I want to access these objects from several other, more procedural, classes. My question is which class should I place the hashtables. I don't want them to be repeatedly read from file.

I had trouble phrasing this question, so if anything is unclear please ask. Thanks for any feedback or answers.

Comment: Couldn't you just pass a reference of the `HashMap` to each class that requires it?

Comment: First, I want to see how far your code has been.

Comment: The more procedural classes are quite independent, so I don't know where I would then create the HashMap   @MadProgrammer

Comment: I not sure I know what you mean @FerdinandNeman, you would like me to post my code?

Comment: Just post some most relevant snippets of your codes to help us understand.

Comment: Well, something must execute these class...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm creating the framework on Java now, but I plan to move it across to android where different activities can access the objects

Comment: @FerdinandNeman There isn't much code that I think would be particularly useful, as I wanted to plan it first before I started writing code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have several classes to store data (DataClassA, DataClassB, etc) and
>   many objects in each class (objectA1, objectA2, objectB1, objectB2,
>   objectB3, etc).

If you only have classes to store data and your application does not have database *(recommended to have one instead)*,. Worth to note at some point in future it will become impossible for you to manage all data in `Object` if your application keeps on increasing in terms of functionality.

> I want to access these objects from several other, more procedural,
>   classes

Okay *what if multiple classes access it same time or try to modify ?* In case of multi threading you should better use thread safe options. Yes! you already used `Hashtable` but that may affect *performance* `ConcurrentHashMap` is a better option though. If you are working on single threaded application you should better have `HashMap` instead.

> Now each of the objects will have an ID number and will be stored in
>   an appropriate hashtable (hashtableA, hashtableB, etc).

So, here you are managing all data in `Object` and store it to `HashTable` with `Id` of `Object`. If it's ***single threaded*** you can try following way,

Create a parent class `Data` which should be extended by all the child data classes.

```
class Data {
    private Long id;//Unique id of Object by using some strategy to allocate unique 

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

public class DataUtils {

    //Created only once for whole application
    private static final Map<Long, Data> DATA_MAP = new HashMap<Long, Data>();

    public void addObjectToMap(Data data) {
        DATA_MAP.put(data.getId(), data);
    }

    public Data getData(Long id) {
        return DATA_MAP.get(id);
    }

}
```

NOTE : This is just an example, you may need to use it accordingly for your case.